# Unexpected token struct in compute shader

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hlsl, compute-shader

I'm using a compute shader to speed up parallel processing of a 3D space computation. The shader gives me compile error **Shader error in 'Polygonize': syntax error: unexpected token 'struct' at kernel Polygonize at Polygonize.compute(10) (on d3d11)**.
Polygonize.compute is the shader file. The weirdest thing is that the first struct doesn't cause an error but the second one does. This is the code: (there's more later but the error occurs at the declaration of the second struct)

```
#pragma kernel Polygonize


struct Points {
  float value;
  int material;
  float3 location;
}

struct vertex {
  float3 location;
  bool weld;
  int weldnumber;
}
```

Comment: @joreldraw what are you talking about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Afaik in shaders (HLSL) the definition of structs ends with `;`

so it should be

```
struct Points {
  float value;
  int material;
  float3 location;
};

struct vertex {
  float3 location;
  bool weld;
  int weldnumber;
};
```